# Get index of row in datatable where a variable is equal

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, indexing

I have a Datatable

```
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.TableName = "Player"; 
        dt.Columns.Add("PlayerNo", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("[2PMissed]", typeof(int));           
        dt.PrimaryKey = new[] { dt.Columns["PlayerNo"] };
```

and I fill the rows from a list "Homelist"

```
    dt.Columns.Add(dc1); dt.Columns.Add(dc2); dt.Columns.Add(dc3); dt.Columns.Add(dc4);
        for (int i = 0; i < Homelist.Count; i++)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(Homelist[i].Key, Homelist[i].Value, Homelist[i].Value.Substring(0, 2), 0);                
        }
```

Also there is another list "events".I get an int value and store it to "plId".
I want to get the index of the row of Datatable "dt" where the column "PlayerNo" of dt is equal to "plId" variable.

```
                int plId = events[i].PlayerId;                    
                int index = dt.Rows.IndexOf(dt.Rows.Find(plId));
```

The PlayerNo column gets unique values(is ID).

I change the datatable definition and I use primary key.Then I use find() method and fix the problem
as here [Get the row next to the row got with DataTable.Select()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121747/get-the-row-next-to-the-row-got-with-datatable-select)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change the datatable definition and I use primary key.Then I use find() method and fix the problem as here Get the row next to the row got with DataTable.Select()